# JPG image partially gray while loading

Tags: jpeg

Anyone knows why the image, shown below, is partially gray while loading? I assume it has something to do with progressive JPG, but I haven't seen the grayscale effect before. Is there some kind of a JPG export setting that enables that? How is it called? Can I disable it?

[image: Progressive JPG loading]

[Direct image link](http://brainly.com/sf/img/mint/main-page/background-web@2x.jpg)

Comment: Looks like two images.

Comment: I think it might have relation to your css, code surround the image. Have you tried to load the image alone with out any css and see how it get loading correct? Just to be sure.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ good idea, unfortunately that's not it - https://i.imgur.com/Tyil2uC.png

Comment: @KonradDzwinel I have made saved the file again just for test (btw this is only temp test not final solution), try to replace it with one your have problem with, but do not delete your old file, just rename it here is background-web@2x_v1.jpg the file https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uyeu2xwhtlk8lbp/AABR8dge4J7hj9gXeJGr9ahMa?dl=0

Comment: @KonradDzwinel any update, please use the file v1 i have in the link to see if the problem appears, because otherwise I might have the solution for you.

Comment: I need to answer soon but I need your contribution regards my previous comments

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ hey thanks for help! Your image loads from the top to the bottom, without the grayscale effect. It's not perfect, I'd prefer it to load in low quality and improve quality as it downloads, as it is now minus the grayscale effect. But anyway, we are on to something here. What are options for exporting JPGs that I should look into? What tool I can use to modify my image? Why grayscale effect happens?

Comment: I will drop you an answer with details why this happen, and eventually how I did it and, and I hope that help you to get the full picture, the test image was only test it can be optimized so you call always optimized it better but perhapes now the cause of the problem hopefully this evening I will get the answer. Btw I was working on iBeacon project and was looking on youtube and found your video that was nice

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ thanks for help again :) I'm glad that you liked my video!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Progressively encoded JPEGs contain ten scan layers by default. That means ten iterative layers of image information build on each other to deliver the final visual quality of the image. The first visible scan layer of a progressive JPEG is always **highly pixelated and often black & white** because it saves on color channel information.

[Source](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2016/even-faster-images-using-http2-and-progressive-jpegs/) (emphasis mine)

Another resource that explores this issue in lengh: http://cloudinary.com/blog/progressive_jpegs_and_green_martians

Comment: + Wow, good article, I was not a ware of that. I have added a note on my answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:**

The problem could either be the problem described in @KonradDzwinel answer OR my answer, both could look identical:

---

### What is the problem

For some reason the file is saved or produced in way that make the file we call it **Lossless JPEG**.

I am not sure which software, tool or how this problem is was produced, but that won’t change the fact that your file had have some issues or even corrupted.

### How to find the problem in the file

Your file was saved in way that it works identical but it had issues. To check whether your file is healthy or not, it requires a tool to scan/analysis the image file. I use a very nice and easy to use tool (software) called JPEGsnoop (link for [download](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-snoop.html)). This tool is free and I used it to scan and analysis your image files for problems.

Your file comes up with few places with following note, (the screen-shot btw shows only one note, but there were more):

> NOTE: Scan parsing doesn’t support this SOF mode.

[image]

After I have re-saved the file correctly and analysis it again, it does not show any problems or notes:

[image]

## What I did to create a problem FREE image file

For testing I have used Photoshop 5.5 to open the Lossless file and save it with new name with default jpeg (since I don't have the original file). But correctly I assume you have the original file, and I assume you have Photoshop any version does not matter OR any other image tool. Try to optimize your jpeg file best possible, analysis it and remember/note the saving setting for future wise image saving.

Here is an example of my Photoshop save settings, which result in problem FREE file:

[image]

### How can I learn more about Lossless JPEG

I won’t go in details of this problem but I will leave some link that explain it in details, I hope also you find this is useful to solve your issue:

- http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/fix-corrupt-jpeg-photo.html
- http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/JPEG
- http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG_%28original%29
- http://www.howtogeek.com/142174/what-lossless-file-formats-are-why-you-shouldnt-convert-lossy-to-lossless/

### Software JPEGsnoop

http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-snoop.html

Comment: Sorry for a late response! Thanks for a detailed answer, I'll try that ASAP.